# Is it possible for a custom view, intended to slide over the main activity, to partially show itself, while the main activity is in focus.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want a view which is partially visible on the main activity and if we click on it, it slides up and shows up completely. Something like "click to show details".

One workaround I have thought of is that when the main activity is in front, a button which looks like the partial custom view appears. On clicking that button, the custom view slides up.

I found an [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120578/android-slide-to-expand-view) which asks for the same solution as I.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I found a library called **StandOut** https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

this might be useful for what you want.